# col-xs doesn't work when the string is little

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My purpose is align a description and some text that represents the description about an object. So in my page i want to have:

Description: (text) (align in this way)

So my html code is:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-xs-1 col-form-label">Description:</label>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <label>ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this case the code work fine because it aligns me the description how I want. But if the string is little like this "sdfsdf", the result is very different because the description and the string are one above the other. Anyone can help me?

Comment: I don't think is correct to mix classes like for example "form-group" and "row". In my answer below, I demonstrate the "bootstrap" way which you may find useful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your error. The only thing I see is both strings overlapping on small screens, which can be fixed with larger column values:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-1 col-xs-3 col-form-label">Description:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
    <label>ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my example I used imaginary field name and column width. You can adapt it to your needs!

Fiddle with 2 input fields here: https://jsfiddle.net/mypp9s38/

Here is another fiddle with description of the labels. The description can be of any size: https://jsfiddle.net/mypp9s38/1/

Comment: @Picco Check this fiddle, and tell me what is it that doesn't suit you: https://jsfiddle.net/mypp9s38/

Comment: @Picco I saw that you already accepted an answer, but you may want to check another approach for adding description to your labels: https://jsfiddle.net/mypp9s38/1/